# Object is appearing behind background

Tags: lua, coronasdk

When I go to the main game scene the image I want to appear does in fact appear but behind the background, I've run through my code several times and can't seem to find the issue. If anyone could help...

```
function scene:create( event )

local sceneGroup = self.view

local background = display.newImage( "game_background.jpg", display.contentWidth,  display.contentHeight )
    background.anchorX = 0
    background.anchorY = 0
    background.x, background.y = 0, 0

local basket = display.newImageRect( "basket.jpg" , 90, 90 )
    basket.x = 170
    basket.y = 10

    sceneGroup:insert( basket )
    sceneGroup:insert( background )
end
```

It is happening in this function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basket is appearing behind the background due to the order in which you are putting them into the sceneGroup. Simply change the order from

```
sceneGroup:insert( basket )
sceneGroup:insert( background )
```

to

```
sceneGroup:insert( background )
sceneGroup:insert( basket )
```

You could also (but not really a solution to your problem cause) use either of these:

```
background:toBack()
```

or

```
basket:toFront()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Frozire, I'm still a noob to programming :P